# Non-integral number vs non-integer number

Tags: terminology

Perhaps a rather silly question but what exactly is the difference between a non-integral number and a non-integer number?

I have heard both being used but I can't really make out the difference between the two.
Is a non-integral number something concerning integrals?

Comment: An integral number is synonymous for an integer. A non-integral number is a number that is not an integer.

Comment: They are synonyms. There is no difference.

Comment: So "integral" can both mean "integral" as in the area between under a graph and "integer"?

Comment: Yes, $\int f(x)dx$ is also called "integral". So the name is the same as for an "integral" solution to $x^2-2y^2=1$, but is has nothing to do with it. So it always depends on the context.

Comment: Integral points are also a thing… so yeah, context.

Comment: True story. There was a lecture announced, the title was something about "integral equations".  So I went, expecting equations involving integrals.  But no, it was about equations with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Languages evolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people call integers integral numbers, but it is not very common. Usually you call "integer numbers"  just integers, so you say 2 is an integer, 1/2 is not an integer.

Comment: It is very common to ask for "integral" solutions of a Diophnatine equation, i.e., like $x^2-2y^2=1$, or $x^3+y^3=z^3$.

Comment: Yep. Someone who knows how to use Google Ngram should probably check, but in my experience "integral solutions" is very commonly used, but describing integers as "integral numbers" is rare, and even sounds a bit off. (I'm a native American English speaker, FWIW.)

Answer (score 1):

To echo Dietrich Burde's comment, the phrase “integral solutions” (i.e., solutions that are integers) is rather common in number theory.

I find myself going out of my way to avoid writing the word “integral” to refer to integers—opting for “integer solutions”, for example, instead—because I irrationally worry that the word gets crucially misunderstood, not as being related to integration, but as meaning essential/fundamental!

I'd be happier to use the word if it has a more distinctive spelling, like “integeral” or “integereal”, instead.

Comment: Is "integer solutions" grammatically dubious? It seems perfectly understandable to me.

Comment: "Grammatically dubious" is probably overly forceful; my point is that "[*fill this in*] solution" seems to require an adjective, which 'integer' isn't.

Comment: nouns very well can act as adjectives too

Comment: Oh yes, nouns too can function as adjectives. So, "seems to require an adjective" ought to be "requires a modifier". Will edit away "grammatically dubious".

Comment: Grammar aside, understandability is the most important

Comment: For sure, clarity is the most important, which is precisely why I said I prefer the perfectly-understandable "integer solutions”. $\quad$ Anyhow, now that we've established that "integer solutions" is grammatically correct, I'm led to wondering: how (in what contexts) might "integral solutions" be advantageous??